# Javascript function invoke with different invoke fashions

Tags: javascript, function

I want to implement the function in javascript let say `Add` that should support bellow formats

```
add(a,b,c)
add(a)(b)(c)
add(a)(b,c)
add(a,b)(c)
```

All these should return `a+b+c`. Is it possible? if so how?

Comment: It is possible, you will need to use `arguments` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the function is run collect the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) parameters into an array, and check it's length. If the length of the array is 3 or greater sum the first 3 numbers using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=b). If not, return the function.

```js
function add() {
  var args = []; // collect the arguments

  function innerAdd() {
    args.push.apply(args, arguments); // add the arguments to args
    
    // if the length of args is under 3 return innerAdd, if not sum the first 3 numers
    return args.length < 3 ? innerAdd : args.slice(0, 3).reduce(function(s, n) {
      return s + n;
    });
  }
  
  return innerAdd.apply(null, arguments); // invoke innerAdd with current arguments
}

var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

console.log(add(a,b,c));
console.log(add(a)(b)(c));
console.log(add(a)(b,c));
console.log(add(a,b)(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```js
function add(){
    let sum = 0;
    for(let e of arguments) sum += e;
    let ret = add.bind(null, sum);
    ret.toString = () => sum;
    ret.valueOf = () => sum;
    return ret;
}


let x = +add(2, 3)(4)(11)
console.log(x, typeof x);
```

Comment: it is returning a function ;(

Comment: see the edited answer

Comment: This is the better answer, as it's not limited to 3..